# I'm not able to clear JTable contents

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel, removeall

```
 tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"id","name","payType","Date"},0);
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        DatesSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

                 while(model.getRowCount()>0) {
                     for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){
                         model.removeRow(i);
                     }
                 }
                 //tableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
                 //tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();


am trying all ans suggested in google.but none of them working.
```

Please let me know how can i clear contents.
am trying all ans suggested in google.but none of them working.
Please let me know how can i clear contents.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh God..i got it....thanks...while am creating MCVE i understand the problem..its not with clear code ..but its static arrayList var that am using is not clearing...oh am struggling from last 2 hours why the clear is not working..but issue with varibale am using

Comment: @user1742919 not `for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){`, wrong you have to loop from max index (`i--` not `i++`) otherwise you are in the risk with `ArraysIndexXxxException` (can freeze `JTable`s view forever)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Looping (sorry but your loop is horrible) just call

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```